# Where to store libraries in cross-platform C++ app?

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform, sdl, game-development

My friend and I decided to start learning C++ game programming using SDL + OpenGL (GLEW), but we don't understand how to configure cmake files yet.

I'm working on Windows and my friend on macOS. So we tried to install SDL separatly for our systems. In many guides and forums about Windows installing I've read that it's a good practice to store library in the project folder but not something like ...../System32 folder. I did it (with this asset SDL2-devel-2.26.4-mingw.zip) using this guide: https://blog.ahmadz.ai/sdl2-for-clion-and-cmake/

But we can't figure out how to do same stuff on Mac. In all of guides which use cmake it tells to store library (SDL2-2.26.4.dmg) in /Library/Frameworks folder. The guide that worked for me on Windows doesn't work with Mac.

So the question is how should we store library, should it be outside or inside our project or it depends on OS? What's best practice to solve with cmake these cross-platform problems when there are two different library versions for each platform? Can you share any examples of cross-platform (Windows + macOS) apps using SDL and cmake?

Comment: You have two extremes: either you build the library as part of your application build process (vendoring) or you assume the user has installed libraries somewhere and CMake can find the libraries (possibly with some hints)